# JCDE plugins in Eclipse doesn`t work ,java card

Tags: eclipse, plugins, javacard

I copy the `eclipse-jcde-0.2` into eclipse'plugin folder ,but the plugins in eclipse doesn't  work,  Do I still lack of something necessary such as FEATURES folder and how can I get the features ?

```
OS:windows
Eclipse version :3.2.
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesn`t work'?

Comment: Care to react on answers and comments, Erin?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response . To see more details in comments for answer .

Answer (score 5):

It is working fine for me. 
I have followed exact instructions from the link [eclipse-jcde](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net)
Only changes I have did is I have used Eclipse 3.5 instead of eclipse 3.2

For Installation in Eclipse 3.5 follow the below steps.

1. After downloading Eclipse 3.5, inside eclipse folder create plugins folder (if already not present.)
2. Paste all the jar files from the downloaded zip file (eclipse-jcde-0.2.zip\plugins folder) to plugins folder (there are 8 jars)
3. Start the eclipse in -clean mode. 
   To Start eclipse in clean mode : On the eclipse folder right click and open command prompt, then issue the command `eclipse -clean`.

Now follow the instruction to set the path for `java-card-dev-kit-home` as mentioned in the above link.
 
 
I am able to create java card project and applet and even start the JCWDE simulator as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much !

My steps are similar to yours , the steps below are the detail.

1. Paste all the jar files from eclipse-jcde-0.2\plugins folder to
   eclipse 3.2 plugin folder.
2.Set the environment variables : JC_HOME , JAVA_HOME , PATH .
   (java_card_kit-2_2_2 , jdk 1.5.04)
3.Start Eclipse 3.2 .CREF ， JavaCard , JCWDE  are present . 
  The problem is that when I choose any one of them and click on 
  preferences , ERROR occur , message : An error has occurred . See 
  error log for more details .but I can`t find somewhere to read the
  log .

Comment: In addtion ,  I try to start eclipse in clean mode , the steps are follow below:
  click on short cut 
  right click -> properties
  add -clean in target clause and then start.
But the problem still exist .

Comment: 1) View by name "Error Log" might help you to see the exception.

Comment: It didn`t show me the location to read "Error Log" .I tried in 3.8 ,the steps are same as I did . The problem is same as I described ,the error message : Unable to create the selected preference page . Bad version number in .class file . It related to "org.eclipse.equinox.registry",I don`t understand what it means .

Comment: Error Log path is : Window -> Show View -> Other... -> General -> Error Log

Comment: Try dropins folder in Eclipse 3.8. Newer versions of Eclipse don't simply support copying in plugins folder.

Comment: I wonder JCDK is necessary ? and how can I tell whether the JCDK work in Eclipse ?

Comment: put into "dropins" folder. Not in dropin folder. For JCDK to work in Eclipse we should set the path from Preferences.

Comment: I put into dropins folder ,and I set the path for JCDK , JDK as well .

Comment: The same problem occured , it drives me crazy .